# how to solve php --ini "Loaded Configuration File:(none)"?

Tags: php

I am trying to install php from source code, but I got a problem here,
I googled it but nothing useful for me.
First, here is my install.sh

```
make clean

./configure \
        --prefix=/usr/local/programs/php5 \
        --disable-fileinfo \
        --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini \
        --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/ \
        --with-apxs2=/usr/local/programs/apache2.4/bin/apxs

if [  0 != $? ]; then
        echo "Auto installation failed! -- Configuration"
        exit
fi

make
if [  0 != $? ]; then
        echo "Auto installation failed! -- Make"
        exit
fi

sudo make install
if [  0 != $? ]; then
        echo "Auto installation failed! -- Configuration"
        exit
fi

echo "Copying the min size config file."
sudo cp php.ini.clean.bk /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini

if [ -a /usr/bin/php ]; then
        sudo rm /usr/bin/php
        sudo ln -s /usr/local/programs/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
fi

php --version
php --ini
```

After the script is done,  I got some weird information here:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini
```

Why `Loaded Configuration File:         (none)` is null, is there anything wrong during the installation ?

Also,

```
$ ls /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/
pear.conf  php.ini  php.ini.bk
```

Comment: not a programming question. please use https://serverfault.com/ instead

Comment: There's no reason to downvote this question, even if it doesn't belong to SO..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is:

```
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini
```

According the configuration help

```
--with-config-file-path=PATH
                          Set the path in which to look for php.ini [PREFIX/lib]
```

You can see, the value of `with-config-file-path` should not contains `php.ini`, 
it's a directory which contains php.ini in under it, so it should be like this:

`--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc`

Another question, why people vote down this question without a reason? except @JimiDini