# PHP module is shown in phpinfo(), but not php -m

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a website. I used the host's control panel to activate several php modules. Now when I try to use them it returns

> Fatal error: Class '...' not found

I checked `phpinfo()` and the classes appear there, but when I do `php -m`, they are missing. The server uses Nginx.

What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: There should be two ini files for cli and apache module. Run `php --ini`

Comment: @mazedlx Done that, here is the output:

`Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
 Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/opt/php56/etc/php
 Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`

BTW, The server uses nginx

Comment: This means that your cli php does not use any ini file. Ok, so please tell us what modules you are trying to use, show the `phpinfo()` output and your code.

Comment: @mazedlx I'm trying to use `Imagick`, the `phpinfo()` output is quite long it can be found [here](http://ecologic-systems.ru/info.php)

Comment: @Rizhiy You can [specify the source of your php.ini file when running cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671610/how-to-solve-php-ini-loaded-configuration-filenone)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Sorry, I'm not quite good at this. How do I find the correct source?

Comment: @Rizhiy You need to figure out what ini file your _web_ installation is using and make sure that your _cli_ installation is using the same ini file. From the look of your `phpinfo` on your _web_ installation, you want to point to the `/home/a2869511/etc/php.ini` file when executing cli scripts. The extension is not loading in the _cli_ installation, as it has no ini file to look for and doesn't know it's supposed to load ImageMagick.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have fixed it. If one of you wants to post an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP web installation and your PHP cli installation *can* be two completely seperate things, and hence they usually have their own ini configuration files.

As per your comment, this is the output you get from your CLI phpinfo:

```
Loaded Configuration File: (none) 
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/opt/php56/etc/php 
Additional .ini files parsed: (none)
```

As you can see there's no "Loaded Configuration File". As per [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671610/how-to-solve-php-ini-loaded-configuration-filenone) you can specify what ini file to load when running cli scripts.

Since your regular web installation says:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /home/a2869511/etc/php.ini
```

Then you can automatically have your CLI program execute with the same ini file:

```
php --with-config-file-path=/home/a2869511/etc/php.ini script.php
```

That said, I would recommend that you take a copy of the ini file and place it where your cli application is looking for ini files, which is in `/usr/opt/php56/etc/php` (`"Scan for additional .ini files in"`).

So the short solution would be to do the following copy:

```
cp /home/a2869511/etc/php.ini /usr/opt/php56/etc/php/php.ini
```