# How reliable is php -m. Can I use it to check all installed php extensions?

Tags: php

I want to test if one of php interpreters in my system has installed some extensions. I noticed that `php -m` shows list of extensions.

Can I use it to test if php has interesting extensions, or should I parse output of `php -i`.

When I do `php -h` i see that -m switch has this description:

`-m               Show compiled in modules`

What are "compiled in modules"? Are they different from ordinary modules?

Do list of extensions from `php -m` can be different from list of installed extensions from phpinfo() or `php -i`?

Comment: "Do list of extensions from php -m can be different from list of installed extensions from phpinfo() or php -i?" have you tried to test that? , however the answer in you main question is yes, you can rely on `php -m`

Comment: `php -m` would probably be similar to `php -i`, but could be different from `phpinfo()`, since there are sometimes different INI files for CLI and FPM/browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695376/php-module-is-shown-in-phpinfo-but-not-php-m for more information.