# php-ast visible in phpinfo but not in php -m (trying to install phan)

Tags: php, php-7.3

How is it that `php-ast` is listed in `phpinfo()` but not when running `$ php -m` to list modules?

Working on installing phan, the static analyzer. I use MAMP Pro and have verified that `$ which php` returns the desired php version within MAMP. I have updated the `php.ini` file, and running `phpinfo()` displays AST as expected.

When I run `vendor/bin/phan` without the flag, I still get the warning that AST should be installed.

I have run it once with the flag to use the polypill parser, and phan works as expected.

[image]

[image]

- Getting started with Phan (see also README for slightly different
  instructions): https://github.com/phan/phan/wiki/Getting-Started
- PHP-AST Project: https://github.com/nikic/php-ast#installation
- Changing PHP: https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693
- Install autoconf to overcome related problem:
  https://gist.github.com/anunay/7698181

Note: Answers elsewhere using `--with-config-file-path` don't seem to be working for me as I get a list of valid PHP console commands and it is not one of them: [PHP module is shown in phpinfo(), but not php -m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695376/php-module-is-shown-in-phpinfo-but-not-php-m)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you need to install the ast extension first.

What I did is this

1. Install PEAR following the instructions in this [post](https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/)

It's basically two commands

```
curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

*Note that I have updated the URL to use https*

I've simply acknowledged the default config during installation of PEAR, hoping that it will not disturb MAMP in normal operation to have some extra directories.

2. Download `ast` from [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net/package/ast), since I couldn't make `pecl install ast` work, maybe it works for you. Then you'll need to run `sudo pear install [path-to-downloaded-ast.tgz]`, replacing the file path with your download location.
3. Edit `php.ini` like you already did, adding the extension.

Result should be this

```
$ php -m

[PHP Modules]
ast
...
```